# How to remove white space between header and content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and have my content inside a wrapper and my header outside of it, and inbetween the two there is a white gap spanning across the whole page from my nav bar (above it) across to the edge of the right hand side as well, how can I fix this? [**Example**](http://www.bootply.com/fdK0rTXSWZ)

I moved `div class="rowimg"` into `div class="row"`, this seems to have fixed the issue for my sidebar but [the content still has a white strip above it](http://www.bootply.com/TUgHZuiZmv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `margin-top: 0` to `.customh1`

Vertical margins on different elements that touch each other (thus have no content, padding, or borders separating them) will collapse, forming a single margin that is equal to the greater of the adjoining margins. This does not happen on horizontal margins (left and right), only vertical (top and bottom).

Here a minimal example to illustrate:

```css
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
}

p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Collapsing Margins</h2>
<div><p>Example text.</p></div>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you